# How to specify path for the folder in Windows

Tags: php, path

I have a form that lets the user to upload files to the server, but I did not know how to write the correct path for that folder in the server which I want the files to be store in, also how to get the path for specific file to download later.

The path in the server:

```
/public_html/upload_files
```

The error I am getting:

> Warning: move_uploaded_file(upload_files/project_guidelines.pdf):
>   failed to open stream: No such file or directory in
>   D:\sites\dwts.com\public_html\website\creat.php on line 50 Warning:
>   move_uploaded_file(): Unable to move 'C:\Windows\Temp\php14AC.tmp' to
>   'upload_files/project_guidelines.pdf' in
>   D:\sites\dwts.com\public_html\website\creat.php on line 50 Error
>   uploading file

Code:

```
$len = count($_FILES['Attachment']['name']);

for($i = 0; $i < $len; $i++) {

$uploadDir = 'upload_files/';

$fileName = $_FILES['Attachment']['name'][$i];
$tmpName = $_FILES['Attachment']['tmp_name'][$i];
$fileSize = $_FILES['Attachment']['size'][$i];
$fileType = $_FILES['Attachment']['type'][$i];

$filePath = $uploadDir . basename($_FILES['Attachment']['name'][$i]);

$result = move_uploaded_file($tmpName,$filePath);
if (!$result) {
    echo "Error uploading file";
    exit;
}
```

Comment: error seems clear- what's the problem?

Comment: i did not know what is the correct directory or the syntaxes, should i write the username for the server ?? (what should i do) :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$uploadDir = 'upload_files/';
```

Where is the drive?  Its Windows, so it needs a drive:

```
$uploadDir = 'c:/upload_files/';
```

You can't give a partial location to the second argument of `move_uploaded_file`...it needs a full path.

Comment: it's uploaded to the server?

Comment: thank you so much :) 
i did not know that i should write the drive 
D:\sites\username\public_html\


it's works now..